# Binding user data on button press

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

I don't know a good way to explain this but what I have so far is I created a dataset and called it `Database` and created a table in it. Then I used a bindingsource and defined `Database` as its datasource.

Then I put the bindingsource as my datagrids data source and I put my textboxs text to the respective column in the bindingsource (e.g. textbox1 text=bindingsource - Name) so I can update my xml so I can click on the row and it fills the textboxes with the rows info and as i edit the text box it changes the data in the rows on the grid view so far an edit and update.

But I want to be able to have the option to update or not. So instead of I type and it changes I want to be able to fill in the boxes then choose to press update or cancel like a normal edit form.

This is my form

[image]

It's as if I could do something like

```
string = textboxname
```

then when I press update it then does selected row column "name" = string

Comment: Have you worked with Event Handlers before, you could use on Selection Changed on the gridview to get the index of the selected item and populate you data on the left form. Edit the details and re-enumerate the gridview with the newly updated list

Comment: i tried something like that before but i couldnt get it to update the row in the grid that was selected it would just add the updated details to a new row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so i figured it out thanks to devTimmy. i was looking in the wrong place and with the wrong ideas.

iv now done it so it takes the selected row index and uses that to fill in the correct row when its told which cell to fill. i didn't think to tell it which cell before so it failed and i thought no more of it. 
here is my code.

```
        int i;
        i = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;

        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = Nametb.Text;
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = Locationtb.Text;
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = Infotb.Text;
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = dayvisittb.Text;
        database1.WriteXml("Database.xml");
```